# Why is my concatinated strings surrounded in curly brackets?python

Tags: python, tkinter, concatenation

Here is a code snippet from a tikinter application I am working on

```
stringGreet = "Hello Employee"+myresults[0],myresults[1]+"who is"+myresults[2]
managerGreeting.set(stringGreet)
raiseFrame(managerMenuFrame)
```

Why does this code result in the concatenated strings being wraped around curly braces?
**Incorrect Result**

[image: result]

**Correct Result**

```
Hello Employee Joe Smalls who is Male
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an incorrect comma, consider using a [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
stringGreet = f"Hello Employee {myresults[0]} {myresults[1]} who is {myresults[2]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You feed a tuple into `managerGreeting.set(stringGreet)`because you create a tuple:

> ```
> stringGreet = "Hello Employee"+myresults[0]  ,  myresults[1]+"who is"+myresults[2]
> ```

Create a single string:

```
stringGreet = "Hello Employee {},{} who is {}".format(myresults[0],myresults[1],myresults[3])
```

You can also use

```
stringGreet = "Hello Employee {},{} who is {}".format(*myresults[:3])
```

instead. If `myresults` only contains 3 elements, remove the `[:3]`.

Comment: Looks like your `.format*(myresults[:3])` is meant to have the `*` inside the format... Also, going down that route, I'd probably be explicit in the format string and just unpack `myresults` without worrying too much about it in case more is needed later, eg: `'Hello Employee {0}, {1} who is {2}'.format(*myresults)`... so then you could maybe do `'Hello Employee {0}, {1} who is {2}, something about {6} and something {4}'.format(*myresults)` etc...